# How can I get the intended page URL for an Edge/Chromium error page?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, chromium

When encountering a "Hmmm… can't reach this page" (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED), `window.location` returns data for the error page:

```
{ 
    ...
    hash: "",
    href: "chrome-error://chromewebdata/",
    ...
}
```

The goal is to build a simple Javascript bookmark that you can click to prefix the current URL (`https://example.com`) with a web proxy URL to fix the error, i.e.:
`javascript://window.location.replace("https://webproxy.com/" + window.location.href)` but cannot currently get the address of intended URL via JS.

Comment: after testing you need to install extension on browser to help javascript itself can't run because at this time dom rendering on sandbox is crashing

Comment: As mentioned, due to security limitations, you may need to use additional extensions to configure proxy settings.